# How to automate the action on a canvas object, when the canvas element has no name or ID in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc

I am having a canvas object, which is used for digital signature...I want to try, to automate that action using selenium...

I found out that,

```
selenium.clickAt("canvas_element_name","co-ordinates");
```

can do the good...`(coordinates like, "30, 40")..But the case is there is no name for the canvas element given...By.xpath is not working in conjunction with selenium.clickAt...

other method, which I found out was,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div/canvas")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div/canvas")).click();
```

But, both didn't work...I even tried try, catch for the second method...

Pls. find the HTML code in the thread, for getting the idea on the element looks like in the page...

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/how-to-automate-the-action-on-a-canvas-object-when-the-canvas-element-has-no-na

Any suggestions and workarounds for this one?

Comment: Try the selenium.clickAt with an xpath and coordinates

Comment: @JayJ. selenium.clickAt("By.xpath(html/body/form/div/canvas)", "30,50"); tried this too...it didn't work...tried with different combinations...selenium.clickAt(By.xpath(" ____", "__"); and selenium.clickAt("By.xpath(' ____')", "__");..nothing worked

Comment: Don't use the By class, just a straight xpath expression

selenium.clickAt("xpath=/html/body/form/div/canvas","30,50")

assuming of course that you only have one form, one div, and one canvas element

Comment: Why are you using Selenium RC? It is very old and deprecated.

Comment: @JayJ. thanks!..there is indeed one canvas element and path is correct, but still am getting the message, element not found...

Comment: @Arran, the Selenium-webdriver also, I tried..But, didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any `<canvas>` element in the source you posted in the other question.

If the element is hidden in a `<frame>` or `<iframe>` element, you must [`driver.switchTo()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html) (for WebDriver) or [`selenium.selectFrame()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectFrame%28java.lang.String%29) (for Selenium RC) the frame first.

If it's created dynamically (via JS), you must [wait for it](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits) [to become usable](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#isElementPresent%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: thanks it did work! :) driver.switchTo().frame("elecsign"); and then I clicked on driver.findElement(By.xpath("//canvas")).click(); it was able to find the element...

Comment: :), read more about swtitching windows and frames [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames). After you're done in the `iframe`, you might want to switch back: [`driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent%28%29)

Comment: I am getting the message, ElementNotVisibleException, I gave, driver.switchTo().defaultContent() and then driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='enter']")).click(); It is a Form and I am about to submit the form...And can I expect this data entered to be stored in the database?

Comment: add @ignore annotation to my previous comment...wrong element..and hence the exception was thrown...But, i am submitting a form using driver, can i expect it to be stored in a database.? its not happening rite now...

Comment: The driver does not do anything special or magical - it does everything you would do through the browser. If you manually click through the process and it gets stored in the dtb, so should it get stored if clicked through by WebDriver. If it doesn't, you do something extra when clicking manually, or there's a bug in the web application.